# .net Core Input field with more than 9 numbers is being passed as 0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a simple create form that passes a value to a stored procedure in my SQL Database. If I input more than 9 numbers, the submitted value is passed as 0.

My Form:

```
<form asp-action="CreateAsync">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LocationId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LocationId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LocationId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" /> |
                <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync(int LocationId)
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"exec GP_Integration_Add_VendorIgnore @p0", LocationId);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "VendorIgnores");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
            
        }
```

My model:

```
public class VendorIgnore
    {
      //  [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Vendor Number must be numeric")]
        [Range(0,99999999999)]
        [Display(Name = "Vendor Number")]
        [Key]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
    }
```

If I enter a number like, 123456789 the LocationId in this line `public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync(int LocationId)` is 123456789

If I add one more number the LocationId is 0.

Comment: The maximum value for an `int` is 2,147,483,647. I suspect you want a `long` property instead.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet That cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

With clarification from @JonSkeet I updated my model to accept specified range of inputs.
`[Range(1999999, 9999999)]`

Comment: That's not the fix I expected - I'd expected you to change the type to `long`.

Comment: Very true, but I had clarification on the requirements, and the id needs to be in that range.